# How do I run nginx -t when nginx is running inside a docker container?

Tags: bash, nginx, docker

Is there a way to run commands like

```
service nginx start
nginx -t
```

when nginx is running in a docker container without having to start the container's bash shell?

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` by specifying them on `docker run`...

If you really need to start a service then add a `; sleep infinity`.

Comment: Sorry, but it's still unclear to me, can you provide an example? Or a link to more info?